# Counting uniques in a colunm that has blanks & zeros from previous work sheets?

Tags: excel

I am trying count the number of unique names in column B on a worksheet. The worksheet that column B is located, copies the values from other worksheets in the same workbook. If there is a blank cell on the previous worksheet it shows as a zero on the worksheet where the formula is located. Names show as names.  I am currently using **{=SUM(1/COUNTIF(B1:B468,B1:B468))}**. However I am not certain that is the correct formula. I am trying to count only unique names and exclude both the blanks & the zeroes. I have checked both similar questions proposed here & on Google. What I found was that they counted uniques with blanks, but not with blanks & zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "counting uniques" I assume you don't want to count the same value twice.....in which case try this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B468<>0)/COUNTIF(B1:B468,B1:B468&""))`

Comment: You are correct. The original formula did count some data more than once. I used a CountA formula & that proved it. This is the better formula, and still simple.

Answer (score 2):

Barry Houdini's solution works, but I think this would be considerably more efficient (though that's not an issue if you only have ~500 records):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B1:B468<>0,MATCH(B1:B468,B1:B468,0)),ROW(B1:B468)),1))
```

Entered as an array formula by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also, regarding ImaginaryHuman072889's answer, the NOT(ISBLANK) test is redundant. This would do the exact same thing (albeit, as Barry Houdini pointed out, wouldn't  account for unique values)

```
= SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B468<>0))
```

Comment: Ha, didn't even realize until now that part was redundant. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((B1:B468<>0)*NOT(ISBLANK(B1:B468)))
```

This counts all entries in the cell range that are non-blank and non-zero.

Comment: The formula that you provided was very easy to understand, once I read it.

Comment: @FrankM `COUNTIFS` was also an option but I typically prefer `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: @FrankM But this doesn't satisfy the "counting uniques" part of the question does it? I posted an answer that does

Comment: How do you count uniques when there is a break in the range? I tried using = SUMPRODUCT((B4:B10,B13:B17<>0)*NOT(ISBLANK(B4:B10,B13:B17))), was told that it is too complicated. I ended up using -2 @ the end of the formula, but I know that is not ideal.